# Convert CSV to Gridded Binary

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to convert a CSV text file with three columns and 572 rows to a gridded binary file (`.bin`) using **gfortran**.

I have two Fortran programs that I have written to achieve this.

The issue is that my binary file size is ending up way too large (9.6GB) by the end, which is not correct.

I have a sneaking suspicion that my `nx` and `ny` values in **ascii2grd.90** are not correct and that is leading to the bad .bin file being created. With such a small list (only 572 rows), I am expecting the final .bin to be more in KBs, not GBs.

**temp.90**

```
!PROGRAM TO CONVERT ASCII TO GRD 
program gridded
real lon(572),lat(572),temp(572)
open(2,file='/home/weather/data/file')
open(3,file='/home/weather/out.dat')
 do 20 i=1,572
 read(2,*)lat(i),lon(i),temp(i)
 write(3,*)temp(i)
20 continue 

stop
end
```

**ascii2grd.f90**

```
!PROGRAM TO CONVERT ASCII TO GRD 
program ascii2grd
parameter(nx=26,ny=22,np=1)
real u(nx,ny,np),temp1(nx,ny)

integer :: reclen
inquire(iolength=reclen)a

open(12,file='/home/weather/test.bin',&
form='unformatted',access='direct',recl=nx*ny*reclen)  
open(11,file='/home/weather/out.dat')
 
 do k=1,np
 read(11,*)((u(j,i,k),j=1,nx),i=1,ny)
10  continue    
 enddo

 rec=1
 do kk=1,np
 write(12,rec=irec)((u(j,i,kk),j=1,nx),i=1,ny)
 write(*,*)'Processing...'
irec=irec+1
 enddo
 write(*,*)'Finished'

stop
end
```

**Sample from out.dat**

```
6.90000010    
15.1999998    
21.2999992    
999.000000    
6.50000000    
10.1000004    
999.000000    
18.0000000    
999.000000    
20.1000004    
15.6000004    
8.30000019    
9.89999962    
999.000000
```

**Sample from file**

```
-69.93500 43.90028 6.9
-69.79722 44.32056 15.2
-69.71076 43.96401 21.3
-69.68333 44.53333 999.00000
-69.55380 45.46462 6.5
-69.53333 46.61667 10.1
-69.1 44.06667 999.00000
-68.81861 44.79722 18.0
-68.69194 45.64778 999.00000
-68.36667 44.45 20.1
-68.30722 47.28500 15.6
-68.05 46.68333 8.3
-68.01333 46.86722 9.9
-67.79194 46.12306 999.00000
```

Comment: you have not initialized `irec`

Comment: @agentp, I believe that `irec` is automatically initialized at 1

Comment: fortran does not automatically initialize variables. Its probably some random garbage which is why you get a huge file.   Why not just do `rec=kk` anyway?

Comment: aside to all this, if you used `streams` access you could simply do `write(12)u` without bothering about record lengths.

Comment: Shouldn't the line `rec=1` be `irec=1`? I think that should solve the problem (albeit clumsily). Please use `implicit none`. It probably would have caught this problem.

Comment: Of course it should! I wrote that under your last question and you still have the same error. You **MUST use `IMPLICIT NONE`**!!! You had this error in your last question and you have it still, please listen and use `implicit none`.

Comment: When I add `implicit none`, I get errors for almost every line in the script

Comment: The reason you get errors is because many of your variables aren't defined. When you add `implicit none`, the compiler doesn't give a default type to the variables and fails, which is great, because it prevents variables from floating around. For example, you would spot that you have two variables `rec` and `irec` that seem to be supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a general strategy like the following:

1. Read the CSV with python/pandas (it could be many other things, although using python will be nice for step 2, as you'll see).  But the important thing is that many other languages are more convenient than fortran for reading a CSV, and that will allow you to check that that step 1 is working before moving on.
2. Output to binary with numpy's `tofile()`.  Also note that numpy will default to 'c' order for arrays so you may need to specify 'f' (fortran) order.

I have a utility at github called [dataset2binary](https://github.com/johne13/dataset2binary) that automates this and may be of interest to you, or you could refer to the code [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68031914/how-can-i-export-pandas-dataframe-to-a-file-with-binary-format-and-let-c-read/71473487#71473487).    That is probably overkill though, because you seem to just be reading one big array of the same datatype.  Nevertheless, the code you'd want will be similar, just simpler.